# why std::string_view is not trivial?

Tags: c++17, string-view

I want to "migrate" to C++17 and am researching it.

I found that this:

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sPnsEM

```
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>

int main(){
    return 
            (std::is_standard_layout_v<std::string_view> ? 10 : 20)
    +
            (std::is_trivial_v<std::string_view> ? 100 : 200)
    +       (std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::string_view> ? 1000 : 2000)
    ;
}
```

returns 1210, e.g. `std::string_view` is `standard_layout` and `trivially_copyable`, but surprisingly is not `trivial`.

I checked some implementation here:

https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/experimental/string_view

and I do not see any d-tor.

Is that because of its c-tors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particular implementation of `string_view` may be trivially copyable and standard layout. But the standard does not *require* this of all `string_view` implementations. So all you're doing is testing whether your particular standard library's version has these properties.

A valid `string_view` implementation cannot be a Trivial type at all. The standard requires that a default-constructed `string_view` be empty, which requires its default constructor to be non-trivial.

Comment: but standard require to be constexpt and trivially copyable?

Comment: @Nick: It is a literal type, yes. But it is not required to be TriviallyCopyable.

Comment: C++23 update: `string_view` is [guaranteed trivially copyable since C++23](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). This arrived via [P2251](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2251r1.pdf), which also made `span<T>` trivially copyable.